# Plugin Location Accuracy Ionic 2

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic3

Estou utilizando uma API `Location Accurancy` Ionic v2 segue o código:

```
cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.canRequest(function(canRequest){
    if(canRequest){
        cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request(function (success){
            console.log("Successfully requested accuracy: "+success.message);
        }, function (error){
           console.error("Accuracy request failed: error code="+error.code+"; error message="+error.message);
           if(error.code !== cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.ERROR_USER_DISAGREED){
               if(window.confirm("Failed to automatically set Location Mode to 'High Accuracy'. Would you like to switch to the Location Settings page and do this manually?")){
                   cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
               }
           }
        }, cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }
});
```

A função "canRequest" sempre retorna false e não faz a solicitação para poder ativar.

Comment: Já tentou usar esse plugin pelo ionicNative?

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a [documentação do plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy) , sobre o método canRequest:

> On Android, this will return true if the app has authorization to use
>   location.

Então podemos supor que o método sempre vai retornar **false** se o seu app não tiver **permissão pra localizar o usuário**. Verifique se você está pedindo essa permissão, geralmente isso é feito em algum arquivo de configuração.